# How to ensure arguments of a template function match the arguments of another argument

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a function that I want to pass to another function of the form.

```
auto f = [](double x) -> double {
    // ...
    return 2.0;
};
```

or of this form:

```
double f(double x) {
    // ...
    return 2.0;
};
```

I want a template function to take f, with another argument that will be used to call f.

something like:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
T use_function(F func, T t)
{
    return func(t);
};
```

But I want to enforce that T has the same type as the return type of f. My main issue is that when I call use function like so:

```
use_function(f, 5);
```

the type of T becomes an int. And I am doing mathsy stuff, which gives me wrong answers using ints. So one solution would be to enforce floating point types somehow...

I am thinking about using this a as a solution:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
auto use_function(F func, T temp) -> decltype(func(temp))
{
    decltype(func(temp)) t = temp; // This will convert to double if temp was an int....
}
```

What do you think about that?

Comment: Make the full plunge to C++17, and make use of the `auto` keyword fully. All you need to do is: `template <typename F, typename T>
auto use_function(F func, T t)
{
    return func(t);
}`. Even if `T` is `int`, if `func` returns a `double`, that's what you'll get.

Comment: To make sure of it I often wrap the functor in a `std::function` object when it is possible. It should give a compile time error if there's any mismatch.

Comment: @Vivick could you type a brief example. not sure what you mean by that

Comment: What I've understood is that you want functions that takes `T` and return `T`. Inside of `use_function` I'd probably use `std::function<T(T)> f = func; return func(t);`

Answer (score 0):

auto return type and perfect forwarding of the argument will allow implicit conversions of the argument to double in an optimally efficient way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

auto f = [](double x) -> double {
    // ...
    return 2.0;
};

double f2(double x) {
    // ...
    return 2.0;
};

struct doubly_thing
{
    operator double() const {
        return 6;
    }
};

template <typename F, typename T>
auto use_function(F func, T&& t)
{
    return func(std::forward<T>(t));  // optimal implicit conversion here
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << use_function(f, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << use_function(f2, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << use_function(f2, doubly_thing()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The OP implies that *more* than just the function call is going on in the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class F, class T, class R=std::result_of_t<F&(T&)>>
R use_function(F func, T t_in) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<R, std::result_of_t<F&(R&)>>::value, "type drift error" );
  R t = std::forward<T>(t_in);
  return func(t);
}
```

this first deduces the return type of `f` based off the argument.  Then it double-checks that if you convert the argument to the return type, you still fet the same type.

It stores this return type in `R`.